# PayPal express checkout doesn't work as expected

Tags: meteor, paypal

I am using PayPal express checkout in my website. It works fine in the development environment when I use my PayPal personal account to register to PayPal.

I removed all the `sandbox` from all PayPal links before hosting my website live. Now, even when the website live, I can only login to PayPal express checkout using my personal account as well.

Why can't I make the payment from whatever PayPal account?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please show error message.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the detail doc: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGoingLive/ Ensure you have setup as mentioned in the doc specially point 1. If you are still facing problem please show error message.

Comment: after I have done the steps throughly. Now, when i click at the "PayPal" button to make the purchase, an empty page shows with "No token passed". and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Please ensure all the configuration value passed. It would be great if you show demo or paste your code here.

Comment: I have created another question and added the code there as well, please if it happen that you were free, check it out :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40648253/paypal-shows-no-token-passed-when-clicking-on-the-paypal-button#

Comment: @BehrouzRiahi sure I will check. Thanks for notifying me